# How do I change `string` to `textarea` (or similar) in Fastfile

Tags: fastlane, fastfile

In the below section there is a `string` field. I can’t find any documentation for it in fastlane and I have no idea what it can be changed to. I would like it to be a `textarea` or something similar, but I don’t want to break my build trying to find a suitable change.

```
parameters {
    gitParameter(
      ...
    )
    choice(...)
    choice(...)
    string(defaultValue: '', description: 'Changelog', name: 'CHANGELOG’)
}
```